# How can I use linerenderer.startColor and linerenderer.startWidth?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void DrawLine(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Color color, float duration = 0.2f)
    {
        GameObject myLine = new GameObject();
        myLine.transform.position = start;
        myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        LineRenderer lr = myLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Alpha Blended Premultiply"));
        lr.SetColors(color, color);
        lr.SetWidth(0.1f, 0.1f);
        lr.SetPosition(0, start);
        lr.SetPosition(1, end);
        GameObject.Destroy(myLine, duration);
    }
```

On this two lines I'm getting warnings:

```
lr.SetColors(color, color);
lr.SetWidth(0.1f, 0.1f);
```

The first line:

'LineRenderer.SetColors(Color, Color)' is obsolete: 'Use startColor, endColor or colorGradient instead.

Second line:

'LineRenderer.SetWidth(float, float)' is obsolete: 'Use startWidth, endWidth or widthCurve instead.'

I couldn't find how to use it by script in the unity documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not actually that hard to use...

```
lr.startColor = color;
lr.endColor = color;
lr.startWidth = 0.1f;
lr.endWidth = 0.1f;
```